# Datetime type conversion using strptime() error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-datetime

I am trying to convert the string which is the date to proper date format using `datetime.strptime()`, but I get an error saying that the argument passed must be str and not Series.

I have parsed the required string column to datetime type and then tried using `datetime.strptime()`, but still I am getting an error saying that the argument passed must be str and not Series.

Could someone help me with the issue?

The code written is as shown below:

```py
data2['Open_Time']=pd.to_datetime(data2['Open_Time'],infer_datetime_format=True).dt.date

from datetime import datetime

import datetime as dt

data3=dt.datetime.strptime(data2['Open_Time'],'%Y-%d-%m')

data3=data2.set_index(['Open_Time'])

data3.head(2)
```

The error message is:

```
      1 from datetime import datetime

      2 import datetime as dt

----> 3 data3=dt.datetime.strptime(data2['Open_Time'],'%Y-%d-%m')

      4 data3=data2.set_index(['Open_Time'])

      5 data3.head(2)

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you can only pass string to strptime(). So what you could do is write a function which takes string as input and do data2['Open_Time'].apply(<function_name>). Inside the function, write return dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%d-%m')

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a Series to strptime, it cannot determine which row it would apply it.

So, you should somehow iterate it if you want to apply to the whole Series.

Here is an example:

```
data3 = data2['Open_Time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%d-%m'))
```

This will iterate data2['Open_Time'] taking each element as x and applying the strptime function.